# Convertir codigo de React 16 a React 18

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

existe alguna app o convertidor de codigo de react 16 a react 18. Tengo un proyecto bajado de github que esta en react 16 pero en mi máquina esta el 18, y quiero ir convirtiéndolo, porque ya no hay soporte de aquel codigo.

Se puede?

```
    import * as React from 'react';
import { onTick } from './EventHandler';

/** Setup the app. Takes care of registering event handlers. */
class App extends React.Component {

    constructor () {
        super();
        this.state = { frameNum: 0 };
    }

    tick = () => {
        requestAnimationFrame(this.tick);
        this.setState({ frameNum: this.state.frameNum + 1 }, onTick);
    };

    componentDidMount () {
        requestAnimationFrame(this.tick);
    }

    render () {
        return (<div className="container">
                <p>Welcome to the camera app.</p>
                </div>);
    }
}

export default App
```

Comment: Puedes usar cualquiera de las herramientas de IA para realizar la tarea de conversión.

Comment: que GRAN respuesta, ya la use y no funcionó por eso puse la pregunta en este foro. Pero se agradece la intención.

Comment: Me parece interesante que las apps de IA no lograron convertir el código o que no funcione, sugiero que expliques lo que hace el componente para poder apoyarte